# Checking bot for admin permissions pytelegrambotapi python

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I had a question: is there a way to check bot itself for admin permissions?
If bot has got an admin permissions such as deleting messages,restricting users it should send message that it has admin permissions, else it should say "give me admin".
I am using pytelegrambotapi, python. Thank you!
Python 3.7

Comment: @Poojan could you describe much more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using [`get_chat_administrators`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/507d524215433b72f34271ad00acb2a530791f05/telebot/apihelper.py#L266)

1. Get admin list of the chat.
2. Check if bot's ID is in the IDs of admins of the chat

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using [`get_chat_administrators`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.get_chat_administrators)

> Use this method to get a list of administrators in a chat. On success, returns an Array of ChatMember objects that contains information about all chat administrators **except other bots**.

This is my piece of code:

```
me = await bot.get_me()
chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(channel_id, me.id)

if type(chat_member) is ChatMemberLeft:
    return

elif not chat_member.can_invite_users:
    return
```

More info [ChatMember](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ChatMember), [ChatMemberAdministrator](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ChatMemberAdministrator)